# Spring Boot running java and web content on different ports in a single application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Is it possible to run static content and java related code on different ports?

I have a spring boot project where my java code resides on `src/main/java` and
web content on `src/main/resources/static`.

Is there a possibility to run static content on port like 8080
and java (rest controller) on 8081 ?

I don't want to create a separate project for UI.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: If it's really static content, you can run an nginx on 8080 off `src/main/resources/static` in addition to Spring Boot.

Comment: I don't think so since they run in the same web container. But you can always create 2 Spring boot applications though it's a weird prerequisite to have them running on different ports. However, creating a Spring boot application to just serve static content seems overkill to me so you might prefer a web server like Apache HTTpd, nginx, ... .

Comment: @Thilo  : Thank you for response.. The reason behind this is i want to restrict people from accessing my UI and serve it as an admisntrator UI  and i dont want to do a role based authorization. Just an inquisite whether it can be done ??

Comment: why not serve static content under different path like http://server:port/context/static

Comment: @Raki_2012 so you plan to restrict people from accessing your UI by running a non secured application on a different port because people won't find out about it? You should google "security through obscurity" and why it's bad.

Comment: You can have a single Spring Boot App with multiple profiles (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205430/how-to-run-spring-boot-as-a-client-application/39206323#39206323), each launching the application using different application-${profile}.properties. However, I'm not sure I see the point, you could just as well follow @kuhajeyan 's advice and set a different context path for the static content.

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure the Spring Boot application to run on port 8080 (or any other desired port) for the REST controllers. You can do this by adding the following property to your application.properties :
   server.port=8080
2. Install Nginx on your server if it's not already installed.

   Create a new Nginx configuration file (e.g., my_static_content.conf) in the Nginx configuration directory (/etc/nginx/conf.d/ or /etc/nginx/sites-available/, depending on your system setup).

   Add the following configuration to the my_static_content.conf file to listen on port 8081 and serve the static content:

```
nginx

server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /path/to/your/spring/boot/app/src/main/resources;
    }
}
```

Replace /path/to/your/spring/boot/app/src/main/resources with the actual path to your Spring Boot application's src/main/resources directory.

Comment: You only missed 6 years and 11 months