# How to run spring-boot as a client application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, entry-point, client-applications

I have **2 Main entry points** in a single application.

The **first main** starts the server, maps the controllers and starts some worker threads. These workers receive messages from cloud queues.

In case of increased load, I want to be able to add additional workers to do my job. So I have a **second Main** entry point in my application which I want to be able to start **without starting the default server** in spring-boot (as a client application) so as to avoid port conflict (and obviously which will lead to failure).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: It'd be better to run this in Spring Cloud and let it manage the horizontal scaling for you.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-and-lattice/

Comment: Other clouds like aws (beanstalk) too can manage horizontal scaling.

Comment: Sure.  My point is that you should let them do it; don't try to manage this yourself.  Be lazy - use what's available.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Launching from the command line with `server` and `client` profiles

To use the same jar and same entry point with 2 different profiles, you should simply provide the Spring profile at runtime, to have distinct application-${profile}.properties loaded (and potentially Conditional Java config triggered).

**Define 2 spring profiles (`client` and `server`)**:

- Each will have its own `application-${profile}.properties`
- The client's properties will disable the web container

**Have a single SpringBootApp and entry point**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(SpringBootApp.class)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

Make this class your main-class.

src/main/resources/**application-server.properties**:

```
spring.application.name=server
server.port=8080
```

src/main/resources/**application-client.properties**:

```
spring.application.name=client
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

**Launch both profiles from the command line**:

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=server YourApp.jar
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=client YourApp.jar
```

You may have `@Configuration` classes triggered conditionally based on the active profile too:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("client")
public class ClientConfig {
    //...
}
```

---

## Launching from the IDE with `server` and `client` profiles

**Launchers**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {
}

public class LauncherServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(SpringBootApp.class)
            .profiles("server")
            .run(args);
    }
}

public class ClientLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(SpringBootApp.class)
            .profiles("client")
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

You may specify **additional configuration classes** (specific to client or server):

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .sources(SpringBootApp.class, ClientSpecificConfiguration.class)
    .profiles("client")
    .web(false)
    .run(args);
```

src/main/resources/**application-server.properties**:

```
spring.application.name=server
server.port=8080
```

src/main/resources/**application-client.properties**:

```
spring.application.name=client
#server.port= in my example, the client is not a webapp
```

---

> Note, you may also have 2 SpringBootApp (`ClientSpringBootApp`,
>   `ServerSpringBootApp`), each with its own main, it's a similar setup
>   which allow you to configure different `AutoConfiguration` or `ComponentScan`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("...")
public class ServerSpringBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(ServerSpringBootApp.class)
            .profiles("server")
            .run(args);
    }
}

//Example of a difference between client and server
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class) 
@ComponentScan("...")
public class ClientSpringBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(ClientSpringBootApp.class)
            .profiles("client")
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I run these two different apps "Server" and "Client" from the terminal? Do I need to have two different builds or can I do it simply using "-cp" ?

Comment: I went through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882752/how-to-configure-pom-xml-to-run-2-java-mains-in-1-maven-project) but it doesn't seem to work with spring-boot.

Comment: Genius! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have an issue with the 2 main classes approach... If I launch 1 class like this (in an EMR cluster):
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-java-options -Dspring.profiles.active=someprofile --conf spark.master=yarn --class com.somecompany.somepackage.firstMainClass s3://path_to_jar then everything works fine. My second main class is identical, same annotations, but if I use same command (switching the class), I get "could not find bean" exceptions for all autowired variables. These both 2 classes live in same package and share classes. How could one work and the other doesn't? Any idea?